# Remove the string before the whitespace

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I want to remove a word before the whitespace. My file structure is:

ant

```
tiger

static rabbit

lion

dynamic monkey

donkey
```

I need the output as:

```
ant

tiger

rabbit

lion

monkey

donkey
```

Can I use a `grep` command for this, or are there any other methods that are available?

Answer (score 5):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{print $NF}' inputfile
```

For your sample input, it'd produce:

```
ant
tiger
rabbit
lion
monkey
donkey
```

---

Using GNU `grep`:

```
grep -oP '\S+$' inputfile
```

---

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/.* //' inputfile
```

---

Using `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/.* //' inputfile
```

Comment: The awk command is working....thank u so much

Comment: Only the `awk` will work fine in case of lines with trailing blanks.

Comment: @RincyRaphael: It's cool that it solved your problem. The etiquette here says you should upvote/accept the answer :)